# Hibernate ManyToMany with clause referencing entity's field value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, where-clause

I have entities Group and Course. Also there is a ManyToMany relation table. I want to get only active courses for the group.

How can I set a condition in @WhereJoinTable() to filter only courses that match: 
Group.isActive = true, and semester_number = Group.currentSemester ?

Or is there another approach to achieve this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "activeCourses")
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();
}



@Entity
        @Table(name = "groups")
        public class Group {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        private String name;

        @Column(name = "current_semester")
        private int currentSemester;

        @Column(name = "total_semesters")
        private int totalSemesters;

        @Column(name = "is_active")
        private Boolean isActive;

        @Column(name = "department_id")
        private long departmentId;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "assigned_courses", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")})
        @WhereJoinTable(clause = "semester_number ="))
        private Set<Course> activeCourses = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by writing a separate query in DAO layer. 
Seems much easier and flexible.